# Calling function outside of adapter in Worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have an object with a function in a `JS` file. 
I am able to invoke that function from a different `JS` file doing the following:

 `car.getCar();` 
but in the worklight adapter I'm not able to do so. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: which version of worklight you are using ?

Comment: @GaurabKumar Server version: 6.2.0.01.20151008-1615

Answer (score 1):

You need to count on your realm to share values between your adapters.
The only APIs you can use are  `WL.Server.setActiveUser(Realm_Name, userIdentity); / WL.Server.getActiveUser(Realm_Name);`

For example:

Let's say you have an array of values in one adapter like

```
var userIdentity = {
  name : "Test1",
  Age : 26
}
```

on first adapter, use `WL.Server.setActiveUser(Realm_Name, userIdentity)`;

to retrieve the userIdentity on the second adapter:

```
var name = WL.Server.getActiveUser(Realm_Name).name;
var age = WL.Server.getActiveUser(Realm_Name).age;
```

PS, your realm name will the one set in your authentication config on the server side.

You could use the above work with functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `WL.Server.invokeProcedure()` API to do this. This way you can invoke a procedure in the second adapter , from the first adapter

More details [in this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#invokeProcedure).